# No status shown below display name

Tags: viber-messenger

When I look at the list of my Viber contacts, I see three different statuses which are online, offline and last seen at. However, there's one particular contact which doesn't have any of it, I mean nothing is written under the name on his contact profile on my phone. What does it mean?

He can't have uninstalled Viber cause his account looks recently refreshed. He has updated his photo along with his Line App. So what does this really mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do Online and Offline mean in Viber?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79227/what-do-online-and-offline-mean-in-viber)

Comment: @bmdixon I don't think it's a dupe of that question. From the original title, this question seems to ask the meaning of those status, but the question body clarified the OP's intent. I've suggested an edit to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Viber has a privacy settings where you can hide that status

you can find that by clicking the "more" button... that is the three stacked horizontal lines, then choose settings then privacy. you get something called "Share 'Online' Status" you can untick that if you want to hide it. Note that you can change it once every 24 hours

Comment: I know it's not asked by OP, but it would be better if you could add the step to do that for the sake of completeness

Comment: no problem, i added it